# Axis2 REST client application with non-Axis2 framework on server side

Tags: apache-axis, rest-client

I need to develop a REST client application that consumes a REST based web service written in some non-Axis2 framework like Apache Slign or Jersey. As far as I can think, this should not be possible as from what I've read from online docs is that Axis2 treats a REST request internally as a SOAP message. If the server side is also Axis2, then it would understand this and handle it gracefully but a non-Axis2 framework should not understand it as a valid REST call and therefore should fail.

Can someone suggest or atleast provide some pointers?

Comment: Please make your question bit more clear ..

Comment: To clarify, Assume there is a REST service implemented using Jersey and I need to invoke this REST service using Axis2 REST client API. Is it feasible? What can be the challenges or road-blocks in this case, if possible?

Comment: That is definitely feasible ...

Comment: Can you explain at least theoretically? In my question, I supported my doubt based on what I read from online docs of Axis2 about REST support. How will you support your reply?

Answer (score 0):

I was part of an Enterprise Service Bus(ESB) development where it had numerous web-services written in Axis2 , Weblogic etc . Also we had various clients which were non-Axis2 as well invoking the services in the ESB .

That is why strongly support my answer .

Comment: Again, I will ask that do you explicitly remember one instance of a non-Axis2 based REST service being consumed by Axis2 client? Why I'm asking this again and again is because my scenario is not SOAP based but purely REST based. So I need confirmation on a non-Axis2 REST service being consumed by a Axis2 client application. I posted the same query on the Axis2 user mailing lists and till now, no one has confirmed that it is possible.

Comment: I'll confirm that once again and inform u ASAP .